# How can I publish an ASP.NET web application in my Sharepoint environment?

Tags: asp.net, solution-package

I'd like to be able to host small custom ASP.NET applications within my Sharepoint environment. For example, I would like to have associates able to access our locations application by pointing to `http://intranet/locations` (Where `http://intranet` is our Sharepoint intranet).

I have tried publishing the application to the `//intranet/DavWWWRoot/locations` folder but received a "system cannot find the file specified" error, which I presume is due to SP blocking certain file types in my project from being copied up.

Is there a way to do this, perhaps using a Sharepoint Solution?

Answer (score 1):

Publish it in a different IIS web site on your SharePoint front end(s).  Your users could access it via http;//intranet:9999(for example), or you could use host headers to provide a more friendly address.

If you do a lot of this type of thing you'll want to look hard at Sharepoint 2013, as its App model opens up a lot of new possibilities in this realm.